# Java code to use Elasticsearch 7.10 on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I want to upgrade my Elasticsearch from 5.5 to 7.10. I am using AWS ES. And I created a new cluster with 7.10 version and try to change the code to use it instead of the previous. I saw that I have to change the code from Jest to RestHighLevelClient, but didn't succeeded to do it. Does someone have an working example for it from the creation of the client, create index, and search?

Comment: Not answering but you should upgrade to 7.17 and even better 8.10. Anyway this is a huge step forward, so 8.10 should be preferred. Note that HLClient is deprecated in 7.17 and removed later. So better to switch directly to the latest client.